# How to store Picture User Profile on Database Table AspNetUsers using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web application. I face issue I can't store Picture User on database table `[dbo].[AspNetUsers]`.

How do I store a personal picture of user on table `[dbo].[AspNetUsers]`.

I already add new column PictureUser on table `[dbo].[AspNetUsers]` to store User Picture.

I need to know what to modify on the controller and view to store user picture on database table.

I'm working on Microsoft identity membership when registering users

my model is:

```
public class RegisterVM
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] PictureUser { get; set; }

}
```

my action controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM registerVM)
{
   
    var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        FullName = registerVM.FullName,
        Email = registerVM.EmailAddress,
        UserName = registerVM.EmailAddress,
        //How to add Image upload Here
    };

    var newUserResponse = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, registerVM.Password);
    if (newUserResponse.Succeeded)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(newUser, isPersistent: false);
  
        return View("RegisterCompleted");
    }
   
    return View(registerVM); 
}
```

on view:

```
@model RegisterVM;

   <form asp-action="Register">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
         //How to add Image upload Here

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-success float-right" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
           
        </div>
    </form>
```

How can I add Image Upload on the View And Controller actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from the `identityUser` class and add the field related to the image. It is also better to save the address of the image.

```
Public class user : identityuser{

 //add image property

   Public string imgUrl {set; get;}

}
```

Comment: this is good but how to make that on view and controller please

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{

 // fetch image data or address from database

    return File(imageData, "image/jpg");
}
```

```html
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { id = 1 })" />
```

Comment: can you give me full sample for that please

Comment: Refer to this address:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-and-Display-Image-from-Database-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx